# Ignore an item infront of another item when clicking in winform

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my first post! I could not find this question asked anywhere, although I apologise in advance if it has already been asked.

Is it possible to ignore a click event on an item in winform, although register that same event on an item behind it?
As an example, I have made a custom drop down menu which is built by some panels and labels. The panels represent the actual items and the labels are just there to show the user what item it is representing.

The user can then click on an item to select it. As of now, I have to manually add click events to both my panels and my labels in front of them, otherwise there is a possibility that the user clicks the actual label and not the panel.
So again, can I make it so that the label is "un-clickable" and wont register the click? I also highlight the panels when I hover the mouse over them, I would also like to ignore the hovering over the labels.

**Here is a picture as an example:**

[image: Image of my drop down with my mouse hovering over an item]

EDIT:
Here is my code handling the drop down menu so far.
I feel like im repeating my self a lot, although it do work.

In the designer (for each panel and label):

> ```
> this.dropdownMeatLabel.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.dropdownMeatLabel_Click);
>             this.dropdownMeatLabel.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.dropdownMeatLabel_MouseEnter);
>             this.dropdownMeatLabel.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.dropdownMeatLabel_MouseLeave);
> ```

In the class itself (the TryToStartTimer() just makes the drop down go up again):

> ```
> private void dropdownMeatPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>             categoryText.Text = "Meat Options";
>             TryToStartTimer();
>         }
>
>         private void dropdownMeatLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>             categoryText.Text = "Meat Options";
>             TryToStartTimer();
>         }
>
>         private void dropdownMeatPanel_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>             dropdownMeatPanel.BackColor = highlightColor;
>         }
>
>         private void dropdownMeatLabel_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>             dropdownMeatPanel.BackColor = highlightColor;
>         }
>
>         private void dropdownMeatPanel_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>             dropdownMeatPanel.BackColor = backColor;
>         }
>
>         private void dropdownMeatLabel_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>             dropdownMeatPanel.BackColor = backColor;
>         }
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please post some of your event handlers? It will help to see what you have tried.

Comment: Absolutely! I will add them to the main question!

Comment: This seems like it would have been much easier to accomplish with the owner-draw option of the standard combobox

Comment: That might be the case, I did actually try that first with little success. Although now that I have done this I really do like the look of it compared to the combobox. Or atleast compared to what I can accomplish with the combobox.

Comment: If you actually WANT to use Labels - you could draw the Text instead or use a Menu - you just need to override the Label's WndProc, trap `WM_NCHITTEST` and set `m.Result = (IntPtr)HTTRANSPARENT;` (`HTTRANSPARENT = -1`,  `WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084`). The Label's now non-selectable and non-clickable (all events *pass through*). I suggest to draw the Text.

Comment: Don't dismiss the `ToolStripDropDown` option, though. It's a highly customizable component, with built-in behaviors that may come in handy here.

Comment: Thank you for your responses! I will try both options and see which I will settle for.